# Upgrade strategy for geoserver 2.1.4 to 2.5.x

Tags: geoserver

I have a 2.1.4. geoserver installation and I wish to upgrade to the latest version which is currently 2.5.2. Can I do this at once by installing the latest version or is it wise to do an intermediate step via geoserver 2.2. and  upgrade further from there?
I noticed for instance that since geoserver 2.2.0 some security changes have been applied. Is it wise to get past this upgrade first and then upgrade further?

Comment: I always just take a backup of the data directory, uninstall the old version and install the new version. So far I haven't had any problems. But I'll wait for someone more experienced to answer this.

Comment: There are no guarantees that upgrade from 2.1.x to 2.5.x succeeds. Such steps are never tested in the development and release process, only upgrading to the next major release. So the most safe path is 2.1->2.2->2.3->2.4->2.5.

Answer (score 1):

As you note, 2.2 is a special case. There are instructions on her to upgrade to 2.2 here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/upgrade.html

I'd suggest starting with that. Once that's done you can probably just jump straight to 2.5.2, the latest current release.

If you want yet more information on the upgrade process and what files change, see:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/migrating.html#migrating-data-directory - which also details how to manually roll back if required.

---

For the upgrade process itself, this depends how you have GeoServer configured. If you copy your `GeoServer_data_directory` somewhere (use this as a backup), you can then upgrade GeoServer by installing the new copy. If things go wrong, use your backup to roll-back.

Comment: I think I'll start with this strategie and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded **from Geoserver 2.1.2 to Geoserver 2.8.3**

First I had some problems and a lot of Errors when I wanted to access the Styles or the **Publishing**-Details of the Layers. But the problem was within my approach. I set up the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR and installed Geoserver within the Tomcat 7 Container but then AFTERWARDS copied the contents of the old DATA into this folder.

After several hours of trying and debugging I finally started again, emptied the **GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR**, removed the Geoserver.war File from the Tomcat, stopped Tomcat, placed the new geoserver.war into the Container and startet Tomcat again.

Now: Surprise, everything works as a charm. Thanks to the Geoserver-Team for this great update routine ... I just wish I had followed the advice step by step. But the upgrade from 2.1 to 2.8 worked perfect!

By the way: my previous errors were:

```
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
... 121 more
2016-03-30 11:55:03,739 ERROR [wicket.RequestCycle] - Error attaching this container for rendering: [MarkupContainer [Component id = listContainer]]
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error attaching this container for rendering: [MarkupContainer [Component id = listContainer]]
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1765)
```